# get logged in user ID from MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am very new in Android.

I want to store the user ID in a global variable from a MySQL database when a user is logged in. I already checked existing login details. Now I want to get that ID in a global variable.

This is my code:

**UserLogin**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    String email = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    new BackgroundWorker().execute(type,email,password);

    //finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(UserLogin.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}

class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    //String result = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://www.mybusket.com/pmsapp/webs/get_all_emp.php";

        try {
            String email_id = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email_id", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email_id, "UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String line="";
            String result="";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
            //result = sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        /*try {
            //GlobalVariable id;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("emp");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                GlobalVariable g = new GlobalVariable();
                g.setId(obj.getInt("empid"));

            }
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to store that employee ID in a global variable. How can I do that?

Comment: please paste your actual PHP, not a screenshot which is barely readable. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.